# how to start the appium 1.6.5 by using .bat file

Tags: batch-file, appium

When I am executing the following .bat file it runs the appium 1.4.16 server.

```
cd \ 
"C:/Program Files/Appium/node.exe" "C:/Program Files/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone
```

Then how to run the 1.6.5 batch file using .bat file

Comment: You mention 2 versions, and none appears in your code sample. You need to give more details, like where are installed the two versions, which code did you try, which error did you get, etc. The more information and context you give, the more chance you have to get an answer.

Comment: When i am starting the appium 1.6.5 using "cd \
"C:/Program Files/Appium/node.exe" "C:/Program Files/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone --udid sr45a5" but it is launched the appium 1.4.16 version only

But when i have passing the cmd as "Appium" then it have started the Appium 1.6.5 version

Comment: Now it have been solved,

C:\Users\username>appium --udid T2334RS23--port 4725 --address 127.0.0.1 --chr
omedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --l
ocal-timezone

Comment: Now it is solved for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it have been solved,

Create the bat file contents as follow:

```
cd \
appium --udid T2334RS23 --port 4725 --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone
```

Comment: appium --udid T2334RS23--port 4725 --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone